# Error while closing the progressdialog

Tags: android

When i am closing  progressbar my project not running..while it runs when i remove the code..
myprogressdialog.cancel()...
i cant understand why it happens??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to cancel the progress in UI Thread not from thread or time thread.

Thanks.